# robot_mechanism_controllers are not seen? (plugin crash)

Tags: ros, pr2-controller-manager

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been trying to get a crustcrawler smart-arm to work in ROS, first with gazebo.
In this last attempt I stripped down the example started with

```
roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
```

But the controllers from robot_mechanism_controllers are NOT seen, in fact there is NO output at all from my launch file after the start of gazebo with my robot.

Please see my (simple)  launch file : http://fwn06.housing.rug.nl/ros/testcontrollers.launch,
the urdf: http://fwn06.housing.rug.nl/ros/smart_arm_gazebo.urdf, and the controller configuration: http://fwn06.housing.rug.nl/ros/smart_arm_control.yaml

"rosservice call /smart_arm/controller_manager/list_controller_types" lists a fair amount of controllers, but none from robot_mechanism_controllers.

I also tried this configuration: http://fwn06.housing.rug.nl/ros/smart_arm_control-1.yaml, which uses controllers mentioned in the list, but nothing different happens.

Am I missing something?  Thanks in advance, Sietse

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206937/robot_mechanism_controllers-are-not-seen?-(plugin-crash)/) by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) on ROS Answers with karma: 168 on 2015-04-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Found out that pr2 uses

```
libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so
```

as plugin instead of  libgazebo_ros_controller.so, so I changed the plugin in my urdf to that.
It now loads the controller manager and tries to parse the robot_description from the parameter server.

The robot is not falling, it is held in position by the controller, I think. But this crashes!

```
        ..........
Dbg plugin model name: smart_arm
[ INFO] [1428668226.366662355, 1.120000000]: starting gazebo_ros_controller_manager plugin in ns: /
[ INFO] [1428668226.367980472, 1.120000000]: Callback thread id=7f9e9daef700
[ INFO] [1428668226.386303567, 1.120000000]: gazebo controller manager plugin is waiting for urdf: //robot_description on the param server.  (make sure there is a rosparam by that name in the ros parameter server, otherwise, this plugin blocks simulation forever).
[ INFO] [1428668226.491614563, 1.120000000]: gazebo controller manager got pr2.xml from param server, parsing it...
 adding actuator elbow_flex_motor
 adding actuator left_finger_motor
 adding actuator right_finger_motor
 adding actuator shoulder_pan_motor
 adding actuator shoulder_pitch_motor
 adding actuator wrist_roll_motor
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 10196, exit code 139, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/gazebo_ros/gzserver -e ode worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/p100213/.ros/log/7a2eff70-df7b-11e4-bd67-002481150e15/gazebo-1.log].
log file: /home/p100213/.ros/log/7a2eff70-df7b-11e4-bd67-002481150e15/gazebo-1*.log
```

A little debugging revealed that it seems to crash in gazebo_ros_controller_manager.cpp,  in line 379.

```
   this->cm_->initXml(doc.RootElement());
```

Is it actually ok to use this plugin in an non-pr2 robot?

UPDATE:
At home I got Ros/Indigo installed from source on Debian/Jessie, which seems to work for the most part!
When I tried the above , I got

```
[ INFO] [1428760883.992343714, 0.524000000]: gazebo controller manager got pr2.xml from param server, parsing it...
Error [Model.cc:779] Exception occured in the Load function of plugin with name[gazebo_ros_controller_manager] and filename[libgazebo_ros_controller_manager.so]. This plugin will not run.
Segmentation fault
[gazebo-1] process has died [pid 15899, exit code 139, cmd /home/sietse/catkin_ws/src/gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_ros/scripts/gzserver -e ode worlds/empty.world __name:=gazebo __log:=/home/sietse/.ros/log/351c4266-e053-11e4-9232-ac220b1a4c95/gazebo-1.log].
log file: /home/sietse/.ros/log/351c4266-e053-11e4-9232-ac220b1a4c95/gazebo-1*.log
```

Also the gazebo view stays black.

Please help, Sietse

---

Originally posted by [Sietse](https://answers.ros.org/users/15266/sietse/) with karma: 168 on 2015-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0